# Drawing a Matrix

Tags: lua, love2d

Im trying to generate a random map using a matrix but I dont really know how. Here is the
function for the matrix. wMap and hMap are the width and height, and mapSprites is a table containing some ground sprites. Also how can I draw the matrix? Im sorry if this is too much of a question, but Im really in need for some help

```
function buildMap(wMap, hMap)
    for i = 1, wMap do
        mt[i] = {}
        for j = 1, hMap do
            mt[i][j] = math.random(mapSprites)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Generating a random map in any programming language will utilize two core concepts: The language's **random function** and **nested for loops**, two for the case of a map/matrix/2d array.

The first problem, is you may or may not have `mt` initialized outside the function. This function assumes the variable exists *outside* of the function and each time the function is called it will overwrite `mt` (or initialize it for the first function call) with random values.

The second problem, the width, `wMap`, and height, `hMap`, of the map are in the wrong order, as maps/matrices/2d arrays first iterate over the height (y dimension) and then the width (x dimension).

The last problem, `mapSpripes` also has to be declared outside the function (which is not clear with your code snippet), which will be the highest possible value the random function can generate. You can read more about `math.random` here: http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial

Consider this function I wrote that makes those adjustments as well as has some additional variables for the minimum and maximum random value. Of course, you can remove these to have it fit your intended purposes.

```
function buildMap(wMap, hMap)
    local minRand = 10
    local maxRand = 20
    for y = 1, hMap do
      matrix[y] = {}
        for x = 1, wMap do
            matrix[y][x] = math.random(minRand, maxRand)
        end
    end
end
```

I suggest you use this function as inspiration for your future iteratins. You can make `minRand` and `maxRand` parameters or make `matrix` a returned value rather than manipulating an already declared `matrix` value outside of the function.

Best of luck!

***EDIT:***

Regarding your second question. Look back at the section I wrote about nested for loops. This will be crucial to "drawing" your map. I believe you have the building blocks to resolve this issue yourself as there isn't enough context provided about what "drawing" looks like. Here is a fundamentally similiar function, based on my previous function, on printing the map:

```
function printMap(matrix)
    for i = 1, #matrix do
        for j = 1, #matrix[i] do
            io.write(matrix[i][j] .. " ")
        end
        io.write("\n")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For choosing random sprite, I recommend you to create a table of sprites and then save index of sprite in matrix. Then you can draw it in same loop, but now, you will iterate over matrix and draw sprite based on sprite index saved in matrix in position given by matrix position (x and y in loop) times size of sprite.

```lua
local sprites, mt = {}, {}
local spriteWidth, spriteHeight = 16, 16 -- Width and height of sprites

function buildMap(wMap, hMap)
    mt = {}
    for i = 1, wMap do
        mt[i] = {}
        for j = 1, hMap do
            mt[i][j] = math.random(#sprites) -- We choose random sprite index (#sprites is length of sprites table)
        end
    end
end


function love.load()
    sprites = {
        love.graphics.newImage('sprite1.png'),
        love.graphics.newImage('sprite2.png'),
        -- ...
    }

    buildMap()
end

function love.draw()
    for y, row in ipairs(mt) do
        for x, spriteIndex in ipairs(row) do
            -- x - 1, because we want to start at 0, 0, but lua table indexing starts at 1
            love.graphics.draw(sprites[spriteIndex], (x - 1) * spriteWidth, (y - 1) * spriteHeight)
        end
    end
end
```